# How to extract links, text and timestamp from webpage via Html Agility Pack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am using Html Agility Pack and are trying to extract the links and link text from the following html code. The webpage is fetched from a remote page and the saved locally as a whole. Then from this local webpage I am trying to extract the links and link text. The webpage naturally has other html code like other links text, etc inside its page but is removed here for clarity.

```
<span class="Subject2"><a href="/some/today.nsf/0/EC8A39D274864X5BC125798B0029E305?open">
Description 1 text here</span> <span class="time">2012-01-20 08:35</span></a><br>
<span class="Subject2"><a href="/some/today.nsf/0/EC8A39XXXX264X5BC125798B0029E312?open">
Description 2 text here</span> <span class="time">2012-01-20 09:35</span></a><br>
```

But the above are the most unique content to work from when trying to extract the links and linktext.

This is what I would like to see as the result

```
<link>/some/today.nsf/0/EC8A39D274864X5BC125798B0029E305</link>
<title>Description 1 text here</title>
<pubDate>Wed, 20 Jan 2012 07:35:00 +0100</pubDate>

<link>/some/today.nsf/0/ EC8A39XXXX264X5BC125798B0029E312</link>
<title>Description 2 text here</title>
<pubDate> Wed, 20 Jan 2012 08:35:00 +0100</pubDate>
```

This is my code so far:

```
var linksOnPage = from lnks in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[starts-with(@class, 'Subject2')]")

(lnks.Name == "a" &&
lnks.Attributes["href"] != null &&
lnks.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0)

select new
{
Url = lnks.Attributes["href"].Value,
Text = lnks.InnerText
Time = lnks. Attributes["time"].Value
};

    foreach (var link in linksOnPage)
        {
            // Loop through.
            Response.Write("<link>" + link.Url + "</link>");
      Response.Write("<title>" + link.Text + "</title>");
      Response.Write("<pubDate>" + link.Time + "</pubDate>");
        }
```

And its not working, I am getting nothing.

So any suggestions and help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I have managed to get the syntax correct now, in order to select the links from the above examples: With the following code:

```
var linksOnPage = from lnks in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='Subject2']//a")
```

This selects the links nicely with url and text, but how do I go about also getting the time stamp?

That is, select the timestamp out of this:

```
<span class="time">2012-01-20 09:35</span></a>
```

which follows each link. And have that output with each link inside the output loop according to the above? Thanks for any help in regards to this.

Comment: I have managed to get the syntax correct now, in order to select the links from the above examples:

With the following code:

var linksOnPage = from lnks in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='Subject2']//a")

This selects the links nicely with url and text, but how do I go about also getting the time stamp? 
That is, select the timestamp out of this: 

<span class="time">2012-01-20 09:35</span></a>

which follows each link. And have that output with each link inside the output loop according to the above?

Thanks for any help in regards to this.

Comment: In the future, you can edit the question to add or change information, so people know the question has changed. I've done it for you this time, but you can clean up your question to help encourage people to answer :)

Comment: ok thanks did not know that. Will do in the future.

Comment: @lars, your HTML code example is malformed; see `<span><a></span><span></span></a>`.

Comment: I know. It is the shape the original webpage are, which I have to live with and deal with!

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML example is malformed, that's why you get unexpected results.

To find your first and second values you'll have to get the `<a>` inside your `<span class='Subject2'>` - the first value is a `href` attribute value, the second is `InnerText` of the anchor. To get the third value you'll have to get the following sibling of the `<span class='Subject2'>` tag and get its `InnerText`.

See, this how you can do it:

```
var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='Subject2']//a");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    if (node.Attributes["href"] != null)
    {
        var link = new XElement("link", node.Attributes["href"].Value);
        var description = new XElement("description", node.InnerText);
        var timeNode = node.SelectSingleNode(
                         "..//following-sibling::span[@class='time']");
        if (timeNode != null)
        {
            var time = new XElement("pubDate", timeNode.InnerText);
            Response.Write(link);
            Response.Write(description);
            Response.Write(time);
        }
    }
}
```

this outputs something like:

```
<link>/some/today.nsf/0/EC8A39D274864X5BC125798B0029E305?open</link>
<description>Description 1 text here</description>
<pubDate>2012-01-20 08:35</pubDate>
<link>/some/today.nsf/0/EC8A39XXXX264X5BC125798B0029E312?open</link>
<description>Description 2 text here</description>
<pubDate>2012-01-20 09:35</pubDate>
```